# Mostrar div centrado de imágenes - HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, div

Quiero que se **muestren todos los accesorioros** (imagen del accesorio y justo debajo su descripción) que tiene una **habitación** en una web de reservas.

Si son 2-3-4 elementos se me ordena correctamente el `div`, el problema es cuando son más de 5 o números impares que se descoloca.

**Mi idea es la siguiente**: sean los que sean (1-5-12) que se colocen centrados en el div en varias líneas y cada línea como mucho tenga 3 elementos, de ahí que en mi código podáis leer lo siguiente:

```
width:30%;
```

**¿Por qué en la imagen se ve descolocado?**

Código:

```
//Cargamos los accesorios de la cabaña en cuestión.
$objeto_accesorios = BD::obtenerAccesoriosPorCabana($cabana->getIdcabana());
$todos_accesorios = BD::todosAccesorios();
foreach($todos_accesorios as $objeto){
    $existe = false;
    foreach($objeto_accesorios as $columna){
        //Si el accesorio global está en el accesorio de la cabaña, true.
        if($objeto->getIdaccesorio() == $columna->getIdaccesorio()){
            $existe = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($existe){
        echo "<div style='float:left; width:30%; margin-bottom: 25px'>
        <img src='imagenes/".$objeto->getDescripcion().".png' height='28px' width='34px' /><br/>
        <label for='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."'>
            <input type='hidden' value='".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' id='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' name='accesorios[]'>".$objeto->getDescripcion().
        "</label></div>";
    }
    $existe = false;
}
```

**Resultado del error:** (Deseo que al ser 5, por ejemplo se coloquen 3 en la primera fila y dos en la segunda, siempre como máximo 3 o 4 por fila)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías crear una variable que te ajuste el porcentaje a la cantidad de tus registros usar un framework como bootstrap.

Comment: @Andrés Una respuesta más adaptable a mi código, sin mencionar otro tipo de frameworks...

Comment: Una posibilidad es reducir el width, pasándolo de 30% a 20% así entran más y luego hacer un div vacío con la propiedad "clear:left" para bajar un nivel y que las opiniones se pospongan un salto de línea más.

Comment: Es dificil tratar de reproducir este ejemplo.

Comment: @LuisFernando Por eso intenté añadir una imagen visual.

Comment: Pero una imagen tampoco ayuda mucho. :(

Comment: Con descolocado te refieres a que lo que se te descoloca es el comentario: "Esta cabaña es grande y cómoda..." que aparece justo después de "MICROONDAS" y debería de aparecer debajo, ¿no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo para lograr la alineación que quieres, no uses float, usa mejor **display: inline-block;** esto causa que los elementos se comporten como flotados pero respondan a atributos en css como si fueran textos y puedes usar la propiedad **text-align: center;** para que (en caso de querer usar 3 columnas) cuando sean 6 o 12, al usar: **30%** estas se alineen perfectamente, cuando sean 5 u 8 queden 2 abajos alineados al centro y cuando sean 4 u 7 el elemento sobrante quede abajo pero centrado, te pongo un ejemplo de cómo lograrlo.

```css
ul, h3{
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: .5em;
}

ul{
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;  
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

li{
  /*cambia este número por el número de columnas que quieras*/
  --n-col: 3 ; 
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  /*La siguiente linea puede ser reemplazada
  * por el porcentaje que desees*/
  width: calc( ( 100% / var(--n-col) ) - (var(--n-col) * 0.35em) );
}

li::before{
  content: '\f011';
  font-family: fontawesome;
  display: block;
  font-size: 6vh;
  padding-bottom: .2em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<h3>5 items</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
</ul>
<h3>7 items</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
</ul>
<h3>6 items</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Una respuesta ejemplar. Así da gusto, entendible totalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Ese comentario te aparece ahí por la propiedad de los **float**.

Para que los comentarios de la imagen no te aparezcan de esta forma debes **envolver** tus accesorios dentro de un **div** y a éste asignarle la propiedad **"display:table"**, para que se genere un (volumen respecto a los elementos en su interior) "anchoxalto" a éste, ya que parecería un div "vacío" sin esta propiedad provocando que aparezca justo después el comentario.

Por ello tu código sería:

```
//Cargamos los accesorios de la cabaña en cuestión.
$objeto_accesorios = BD::obtenerAccesoriosPorCabana($cabana->getIdcabana());
$todos_accesorios = BD::todosAccesorios();
echo '<div style="display:table">'; // Lo recogemos en un div
foreach($todos_accesorios as $objeto){
    $existe = false;
    foreach($objeto_accesorios as $columna){
        //Si el accesorio global está en el accesorio de la cabaña, true.
        if($objeto->getIdaccesorio() == $columna->getIdaccesorio()){
            $existe = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($existe){
        echo "<div style='float:left; width:30%; margin-bottom: 25px'>
        <img src='imagenes/".$objeto->getDescripcion().".png' height='28px' width='34px' /><br/>
        <label for='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."'>
            <input type='hidden' value='".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' id='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' name='accesorios[]'>".$objeto->getDescripcion().
        "</label></div>";
    }
    $existe = false;
}
echo '</div>';
```

Añado la demo que he realizado para ello: https://jsfiddle.net/s428Lc67/1/